# Filter no delphi não funciona com acento

Tags: delphi

Ao pesquisar:

```
AQuery.Filter := 'nome LIKE ''%jose%''';
```

O resultado **José da Silva** não é mostrado devido ao acento na letra **é**.

Pesquisei vários assuntos relacionados e percebi que:

1. A chamada MySQL funciona normal quando estou usando meu gestor de banco de dados.

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas
WHERE nome LIKE '%jose%'
```

Esse comando me retorna como o esperado o **José da Silva**.

2. Fazendo a chamada com `SELECT` no delphi funciona.

```
AQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE ''%jose%''');
```

Esse comando me retorna como o esperado o **José da Silva**.

3. Fazendo a chamada com `Filter` no delphi **NÃO** funciona

```
Filter := 'nome LIKE ''%jose%''';
```

Esse comando **NÃO** me retorna o **José da Silva**.

**Problema**

Eu só não obtenho o que desejo quando uso o `Filter`, então há algum problema nesse método.

**Soluções**

Tentei várias soluções, dentre elas o comando.

```
Filter := 'Upper(nome_pessoa) like '+QuotedStr('%'+ AnsiUpperCase(Texto)+'%');
```

Porém, não tive sucesso.

Comment: Qual a classe de `AQuery`?

Comment: A classe é `TFDQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, você precisa apenas modificar o collation do banco de dados.

Algo como:

`ALTER DATABASE "nome_banco_dados" CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;`

1. **latin1_general_ci**: Não há distinção entre letras maiúsculas e
   minúsculas. Buscando por “teste”, registros como “Teste” ou “TESTE”
   serão retornados.
2. **latin1_general_cs**: Distingue letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.
   Buscando por “teste” somente retornará “teste”. Opções como “Teste”
   e “TESTE” não serão retornadas.
3. **latin1_swedish_ci**: Não distingue letras minúsculas e maiúsculas e
   nem caracteres acentuados e com cedilha, ou seja, o registro que
   contém a palavra “Intuição” será retornado quando houver uma procura
   pela palavra “intúicao”.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção amigo. Infelizmente não deu certo. Como disse, o problema parece não estar no banco de dados. A pesquisa sem acento funciona normalmente no MySQL-Front e quando uso `TFDQuery.Open()`. O problema apenas acontece no `Filter` do `TFDQuery`. De alguma forma o `Filter` não reconhece os acentos. Acredito que deveria ser feita alguma mudança nas opções de filter do query assim como quando uso `qryPessoas.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];`.

Answer (score 1):

Pra resolver esse problema, crie uma função que remova os caracteres especiais como acentuação, e coloque ela assim:

```
'Upper(nome_pessoa) like '+QuotedStr('%'+ AnsiUpperCase(Substitui(Texto))+'%')
```

onde substitui será a função para substituição dos caracteres especiais para comuns.

Aqui esta um exemplo de função que faz isso: [Função substitui caracter](https://www.marcosregis.com/substituir-caracteres-especiais-strings-delphi/)!